# Get rid of last four characters in VBA concatenated text box

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, concatenation

I have a code I use to concatenate highlighted cells with a separating " OR " between them. It places the data into a text box. My problem is that it adds a final " OR " to the end of the text string. I would like the text to automatically get rid of the last " OR " or to not put it in at all.

```
 Dim rCell As Range, strJoin As String
 Dim box As TextBox
 Set box = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes.Add(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Left, _
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Top, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Left, _
 ActiveCell.Offset(6, 1).Top)

 With box
 .Text = vbNullString

 For Each rCell In Selection
 strJoin = rCell
 box.Text = box.Text & strJoin & " OR "
 Next rCell

 End With

End Sub
```

I have a series of these that I use to create SQL queries, and not having to manually remove the last word would be lovely.

Thank you in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: `box.Text = LEFT(box.Text, LEN(box.Text)-4)` after the `Next rCell` Line

Answer (score 0):

I like this pattern:

```
Dim sep as string

For Each rCell In Selection
    box.Text = box.Text & sep & rCell.Value
    sep = " OR "
Next rCell
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That did it.